# Counts of categorical values on bar chart in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Kind of an R newbie here, so forgive me if this ends up being an embarrassingly easy fix. I'm looking for a way to get my bar chart to display the counts of categorical values in ggplot2.

I've put together some made-up sample data:

```
ID  Age SizeOfTumor RemovalSurgery
1   <30 Small   No
2   <30 Large   Yes
3   <30 Large   No
4   <30 Small   No
5   <30 Small   No
6   <30 Large   Yes
7   30-60   Large   No
8   30-60   Large   Yes
9   30-60   Large   Yes
10  30-60   Small   Yes
11  30-60   Small   Yes
12  30-60   Small   No
13  30-60   Large   No
14  30-60   Small   No
15  >60 Large   Yes
16  >60 Large   Yes
17  >60 Large   Yes
18  >60 Small   Yes
19  >60 Small   No
20  >60 Large   Yes
```

And plotted it using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = SizeOfTumor, fill = RemovalSurgery)) + geom_bar(position = "fill") + facet_grid(~Age)
```

Which churns out
  [a pretty standard barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg6ar.png)

What I'd like to do is be able to add the numbers for each categorical variable to the chart while retaining the percent scale.

- I've looked up a few similar questions and tried several varieties of geom_text code with no luck.
- I think the difference might be in that I don't have y as its own column, just the counts as the fill.

Any advice would be appreciated. I'd rather not have to go into photoshop and manually type in all the labels.

Comment: Can you use `dput` instead of copying the text? What you are asking is pretty easy, but reading your example data into R is not.

Comment: Apologies; I'll keep that in mind if I have any future questions. I tend to import my data from .csv files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I would recommend doing your own summarizing rather than letting `ggplot` do it for you.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

plot_data <- df %>% 
  count(SizeOfTumor, Age, RemovalSurgery) %>% 
  group_by(Age, SizeOfTumor) %>% 
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n))


ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = SizeOfTumor, y = percent, fill = RemovalSurgery)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") + 
  geom_label(aes(label = percent(percent)), position = "fill", color = "white", vjust = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  facet_grid(~Age)
```

[image]

I also added some formatting of the y_axis and the text in `geom_label` with `percent` from the `scales` packages.

Comment: Managed to finagle this into what I was looking for! Thanks so much.